# How to change a file's extension to something else?

Tags: windows, file-extension, file-browser

I downloaded an .R file from a zoom chat on desktop to open in Rstudio later.

Well, the .R extension was not part of the name, so I changed the name to `something.pdf` (of course by mistake).

The icon now looks like a pdf. I replaced the .pdf with .R. But the icon still is a PDF file and Rstudio does not recognize it as an R file.

How can I can change it back to its .R format?

edit. thanks for pointing this out. I am on a windows 10 machine. and the file is on desktop.

Comment: https://sawtoothsoftware.com/resources/knowledge-base/general-issues/how-to-show-file-name-extensions-in-windows-explorer

Comment: Which operating system? Windows? macOS?

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshoot for Windows

You may be trying to add multiple file extensions, which does not allow the file to be ready correctly.

A quick google search.

How do I reveal file extensions?

For Windows 8-10

1. Start Windows Explorer, you can do this by opening up any folder.
2. Click the View menu.
3. Check the box next to "File name Extensions"

Then make sure you have `my_file.R` as opposed to `my_file.R.R.pdf`.

Comment: Like my comment please, glad to hear it worked for you!